# Metric topology but not group topology

Tags: general-topology

I am looking for a metric $d$ that defined on a group $X$ but $(X,d)$ fails to be a group topology. For the semimetric, the following construction will do:

Consider the additive group ${\bf{Z}}$ with semimetric $d$ such that $d(j,k)=d(k,j)=0$ if $j=k$ or $j<k\leq 0$, take $d(j,k)=1=d(k,j)$ if $j>k\geq 0$ and $d(j,k)=d(k,j)=d(0,k)=1$ if $j\leq 0\leq k$, one can check that there are no neighbourhoods $U$ of $0$ and $V$ of $1$ such that $U+V\subseteq B(1,\frac{1}{2})$.

So what about the metric one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X = \mathbb{Z}$. Let $Y = \{0\} \cup \{\frac{1}{n}: n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ in the usual topology (so a convergent sequence) and let $f$ be a bijection from $X$ onto $Y$, which can be done as both are countable sets.

Define $d(x,y) = |f(x) - f(y)|$. This is a metric (easy to check) that makes $\mathbb{Z}$ isometric to $Y$.

Basic fact: if $X$ is a topological group (under $\ast$, say), $X$ is *homogeneous*: i.e. for every $x,y \in X$, there exists a homeomorphism $h: X \rightarrow X$ such that $h(x) = y$. Proof: the map $h(z) = (y \ast x^{-1}) \ast z$ (check this).

And $X$ in this topology is not homogeneous (as $Y$ is not, check this too).